# Unable to install My program. Mostly has to do with Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Okay, This question has probably been asked before but I can't seem to solve it with anything that I've seen.
I published my program and tried setting it up on another computer. At first it gave me this error:

> "Unable to install or run the application.  the application requires that assembly microsoft.reportviewer.processingobjectmodel version 9.0.0.0 be installed in the global assembly cache (GAC) first."

After searching I found that including everything in the 'Application Files' before publishing made that go away, only to be replaced with

> 'Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.'

After searching and doing a lot of things on the computer that I want this program to be setup on, I checked (Crystal Report Basic For Visual Studio 2008 (x84, x64)) in the Prerequisite.
On the Computer that I need this program on, it won't download this at all. It gives me a message box to either retry or cancel.
Some pages suggest that the Crystal report package that automatically downloads is not the right one. When I tried following what is said [here](http://search.sap.com/ui/notes?id=0001534388&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031353334333838&ssocompatible), I got stuck because the links won't open.
Any help appreciated, It's frustrating because I've been working on this program for months and I get stuck on the last step :/

oh .. and ... I don't know if this has anything to do with this, but I built the program using Windows 7, then updated to Windows 8, then updated to Windows 10.

Comment: Oh, wow .. not a single reply ... How encouraging -_-

Comment: have you tried installing your application in some other computer other than the one you are testing on now?

Comment: Yes .. I tried installing it on two different Computers. They both give me the same 'Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.'

Comment: I also tried to make an installer like mentioned [here](http://www.fryan0911.com/2010/07/how-to-create-setup-and-deployment.html). Still no luck :/

Comment: Now I get This error: An error occurred downloading the following resource:
http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/downloads/redistributables/vs_2008/redist/x64/CRRedist2008_x64.msi

Date: 2/23/2016 11:51:53 AM

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\ZENAB_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD7AFD.tmp\install.log' for more information. ... Even on the original Computer that I work on (Which I made the program on) I get this error :/ .... @Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work :)

Here is what I did:

1. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CXV3ff9UDw) video and I was able to install my program to the other computer.
2. When I opened it, I got a problem that the program can't find my MS Access DataBase, so I went to the setup project -> Right click -> add -> File, And I navigated to my original project's folder and added everything in there, and Viola! ... It works :)

I hope this helps somebody else :)